# Spring test invalid configuration

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

I have a simple REST controller that I'm trying to test, the test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ModelControllerTests {
    private MediaType contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8;
    private HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private ModelService service;

    @InjectMocks
    private ModelController controller;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    void setConverters(HttpMessageConverter<?>[] converters) {
        jacksonConverter = Arrays.stream(converters)
                .filter(hmc -> hmc instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
                .findAny()
                .orElse(null);

        assertNotNull(jacksonConverter);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void postModel_returnsModel() throws Exception {
        when(service.doSomething(any())).thenReturn(new Model("cde", null));

        mockMvc.perform(post("/model")
                .content(json(new Model("abc", null)))
                .contentType(contentType))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json("{\"notEmpty\":\"abc\"}", true));
    }

    private String json(Object o) throws IOException {
        var responseMessage = new MockHttpOutputMessage();
        jacksonConverter.write(o, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8, responseMessage);
        return responseMessage.getBodyAsString();
    }
}
```

Now I've got a problem with dependencies and configuration, I've got the following line in my application.properties: `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null`, which works fine when using the normal mockMvc (webAppContextSetup), however I wanted to mock `ModelService` (which is autowired in `ModelController`.

When using `standaloneSetup` to create MockMvc instance there seems to be no configuration, fields that are set to null are returned and furthermore it seems that the ModelService annotated with @Mock is not the same as the one in ModelController, therefore when `postModel_returnsModel` it's using the wrong service.

How can I solve this?